# Javascript Random Image Losing Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

trying to set up random background images for my Jumbotron. Here is what I have so far.

```js
function randomImage() {
  var images = [
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZwkTaJg28-Bxidgfm6FbHyEZ8D5ya1hGMroF05htuwvQqJsY9sQ",
    "http://www.shunvmall.com/data/out/193/47120931-random-image.png",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2b/05/14/2b05140a776f25a8047c88fbe2bcbdb9.jpg"
  ];
  var imgAmount = images.length
  console.log(imgAmount);
  var x = Math.floor(imgAmount * Math.random())
  console.log(x);
  document.getElementsByClassName('jumbotron')[0].style.background = "url(" + images[x] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
}
window.onload = randomImage;
```

This works however on page load the styles defined in my css sheet seem to be overwritten?

```css
.container .jumbotron {
  background: url(/static/images/banner-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Is there a way to load these random images and keep the other styles already defined?

Also, another quick question.. I used getElementsByClassName[0] only because I couldn't get querySelector to work. How would I have written this with querySelector?

Comment: Can you post a workable code snippet, with the HTML?

Comment: Well, for the query selector it would look something like this: document.querySelector('.jumbotron')

Comment: @user218046 I was going to comment back and say that's the first thing I tried! But it works now, must have been a typo. How embarrassing.. Thanks!

Comment: check if window.onload is really firing and not overridden somewhere else. Otherwise the code should work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/oo1ac4gw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `style.background` property using JavaScript *resets* all the background properties (including `background-size` as well). You might only want to alter the `backgroundImage` property using JavaScript to keep the other background styles defined in your CSS.

```
document.querySelector('.jumbotron').style.backgroundImage = 'url(...)';
```

```js
function randomImage() {
  var images = [
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZwkTaJg28-Bxidgfm6FbHyEZ8D5ya1hGMroF05htuwvQqJsY9sQ",
    "http://www.shunvmall.com/data/out/193/47120931-random-image.png",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2b/05/14/2b05140a776f25a8047c88fbe2bcbdb9.jpg"
  ];
  var imgAmount = images.length;
  var x = Math.floor(imgAmount * Math.random());
  document.querySelector('.jumbotron').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[x] + ")";
}

window.onload = randomImage;
```

```css
.container .jumbotron {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/300x200) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px #000 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Changing .style.background to .style.backgroundImage worked perfectly. Who knew something so little could cause such grief. Thank you!